# developing Cross Platform applications

Tags: web-applications, mobile, cross-platform, desktop-application

I wish to keep this question as broad as possible, I got a job in Linux environment.  As of now, I am a programmer with VB.net only, now, I want/require to focus on multiple platform like Linux, windows, android and web apps simultaneously.  I am open to learn new language for this purpose, the options I consider going to are JAVA and Python,  from what I heard, Python is easy to use and tough on performance and deployment, and Java is good in mostly all common aspects like performance, deployment, libraries etc.

Could you please suggest what is good in terms of cross platform for both desktop apps and web apps production.  I am open to any new software because vb.net is somewhat restricted to windows only (Linux is supported partly via third party software).

Comment: I never used c++ but web says it is a good for cross platform too..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will recommend python for sure :)
python runs on linux, windows, mac osx, iphone, android, ps2, ps3, psp, ipod nano&touch and more...
The standard library is very great

and you can do anything with it (games, ui, web dev...)
 here is a list of program which are made in python:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software

nasa, google, wikipedia uses python

Python is compilable with py2exe

for more information google it

I hope you will enjoy python if you get in

Comment: This is not answer. It's barely a comment, but a comment would be better use for this opinionated statement without any information or evidence to back it up!

Comment: Its better now youve edited your answer!

Comment: How about the speed of processing, from browsing they say Python is slow, does this mean that the User would come to know that the app is slow or is this slow is only a fraction and on todays systems/devices this is not an issue for small apps?

Comment: Obviously you don't know pypy

Comment: I am new to Python as said; does this mean that he PYPY and standard python have different syntax etc? I mean, the variants among python have same code pattern or not.  Thank you.

Comment: pypy is just a faster interpreter so of course the syntax is the same as cpython

Answer (score 1):

Coming from VB.NET, you should check out [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com). It is similar to VB.NET from a language and IDE standpoint and runs natively on Linux (as well as Windows and OS X).  It creates cross-platform apps for Linux, Windows, OS X and the Web. It cannot directly create Android apps, but its web applications work fine on mobile devices.

Comment: It is paid version, yet considerable option.  Thank you.

Comment: Real Studio is now known as Xojo. http://www.xojo.com